# iPhone OS 3.2 on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode3.2

I have edited this OS 3.2 question based on advice that it could infringe Apple's NDA which is something I have no desire to do. For what its worth I didn't reveal anything likely to upset their lawyers. And in my opinion the SDK is their IP, and therefore it's their decision regarding the terms we agree to when optionally downloading it.

Without breaking NDA I can summarize that it asked for opinion on whether OS features of iPad were likely to become part of the iPhone OS. But consider the question withdrawn...

Comment: You do know you're under NDA right now with the iPad enhancements to Cocoa Touch, right? I think there won't be a lot of technical discussion until the NDA's lifted - my guess is once the 3G iPads are out, but who knows. Maybe it won't be till after WWDC.

Comment: *Even* without the NDA it's still too early to give any conclusions. It's still a beta.

Comment: Just because you're under NDA doesn't mean the original poster is (according to The Great And Good™ when I asked about same on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/can-i-close-a-question-as-subject-under-non-disclosure)

Comment: If you really want to withdraw your question, you should delete it. You've edited it to make very little sense, but you haven't protected yourself because the previous revisions are available in the edit history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely that by the time the iPad comes out, there will be a new version of the iPhone OS. Whether that's 3.2 or whether it gets bumped all the way up to 4.0 is likely going to be on how much new stuff there is; though my bet is that Apple has worked its way through a lot of engineering resources for the iPad and as such, there won't be that much new-and-noteworthy in the next iPhone/iPad release. We may have to wait longer for other long-desired features (like background tasks).

Comment: The irony to me is that the longer apple waits regarding the discussion of multitasking, the harder it will be for them to deliver. They drive the thousands of app store developers hard on memory management, but seem easy going regarding their consumption of CPU cycles. They should be demanding thoughtful prioritization of execution threads about now if they wanted to allow some kind of co-existance in the future?

Comment: @Nigel - I don't think it's that big a leap.  Most people today doing background threads use NSOperationQueues, which are easy to control the priority of - so if they do allow multitasking in the future, then we'll have some guidelines for how to set that properly but the underlying system will probably have some degree of throttling over your app anyway.  That's all assuming the iPhone will even allow multitasking, which I'm not sure it will for some time to come as I think they are taking this design philosophy as far as they can take it.